# Get-Mailboxpermission for a group of users

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm needing to get mailbox permissions for each user in an OU has to any shared mailbox. I've exported the list of users into a CSV tried imported that list while doing a foreach however when I run the script it keeps asking for the identity. Below the code, I've tried running.

```
Import-CSV $outfile | foreach {
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox,SharedMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | foreach -process {Get-MailboxPermission -user $_."Primary SMTP Address"} |
where {$_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false} | ft id*,user,accessrights -Wrap | Export-Csv $outbox -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I've also tried using -OrganizationalUnit but it ends up grabbing user permissions for the entire domain.

```
Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox,SharedMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | 
where {$_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false} | ft id*,user,accessrights -Wrap
```

Any help or suggestions on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you break these up into single commands until you have a good understanding of what they do and how they work.

This command as written gets every user/shared mailbox.

```
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox,SharedMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited
```

You're gathering every mailbox each iteration of the loop.

This command would get permissions for a single mailbox if the mailbox is piped into it or passed in through parameter

```
$mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission
```

or

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $mailbox.identity
```

Adding the user would get mailbox permissions that are granted or denied for the specified user, should any exist. There is a good chance that you would be querying the same mailbox many times for different users.

I am not aware of a way to take a user and find all mailboxes they have rights granted/denied without iterating all mailboxes. So I recommend we first get all mailboxes and their individual rights (both denied or not, and you could further filter for either/or.) The Identity is the canonical name, I'm guessing you would prefer the email address of the mailbox.

```
# To keep the command line smaller we'll save the filter in a variable
$wherefilter = {$_.user -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.isinherited -eq $false}

# Get all mailboxes and each right assigned to them, stored as a hashtable
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails usermailbox,sharedmailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($permission in Get-MailboxPermission $_.identity | Where-Object $wherefilter)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Mailbox      = $_.PrimarySMTPAddress
            User         = $permission.user
            Type         = $_.recipienttype
            AccessRights = $($permission.accessrights)
            Deny         = $permission.deny
        }
    }
} -OutVariable permissions
```

By using the `-OutVariable` parameter, we get to see the data and store in a variable at once. The output will be objects that look like this

[image: output object]

Finally, If you create a hash table (lookup table) with this data it can simplify the final part of gathering all permissions per user. The `Group-Object` command has a handy `-AsHashTable` parameter that we can take advantage of.

```
$permissions = $permissions | Group-Object -Property {$_.user.split('\')[1]} -AsHashTable -AsString
```

Now you can take your list of users and with their SamAccountName retrieve any permission they have using dot notation

```
Import-CSV $outfile |
    ForEach-Object {$permissions.($_.samaccountname)} |
        Export-Csv $outbox -NoTypeInformation
```

One last note - you only want to use the `Format-*` cmdlets for console output. Do not try to pipe them to other cmdlets such as `Export-Csv` as the formatted output is no longer well formed objects.

Comment: Thank you Doug, this works great, it pulled up all permissions for all 300+ shared mailboxes. The output file came out blank. I need to filter this down to only users in a certain OU. The CSV file I'm importing has several columns so I added `select "Primary SMTP Address" ` to make it look like 

`Import-CSV $outfile | select "Primary SMTP Address" |` but with no avail.

Comment: No unfortunately the file came out blank.

Comment: Well then I’d say you don’t have any that match the filter

Comment: I would agree with you however I can pull up a user from the OU in Exchange ECP and find shared mailboxes they have access to, so I would assume this user should of been listed in the outfile.